# force browser to download a file instead viewing it

Tags: pdf, browser

On my web I want to have two buttons - first `Download` that should download a pdf to the user's computer and another `View` that opens pdf in a new tab. The thing is, I don't know how to make the `Download` button. You might say that it is useless as you can save pdf after "viewing" it but I have already made graphics like that and don't really want to change it. Is it possible to prevent browser from opening the pdf file and make it download the file instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to force file download in your server-side script:

Here is a PHP example:

```
$file = "path/to/my-file.pdf";

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Comment: cool, can you just tell me explicitly what line is causing the behaviour change?

Comment: There is no specifically line which cause viewing of a pdf file. If the browser recognize the type of the file you're visiting then it will automatically try to show it, if it doesn't know what file it is, then it will ask you to download. Using these lines of codes, which I've gave to you, the download is forced and the browser will not try to show the file.

Comment: Matei; There is no Content-Transfer-Encoding header field in HTTP. Also, Content-Description is just noise. Finally, a filename using forward slashed would need to be quoted (see RFC 6266), but UAs will throw path information away anyway, so there's no point in sending it in the first place.

clime: the relevant header field is Content-Disposition.

Comment: Thank you Julian, that was useful comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, as I use nginx, I decided to solve this at http-server level:

```
location /media  {
    alias /srv/www/novacek/media/;
}

location /download/media {
    alias /srv/www/novacek/media/;
    add_header Content-Disposition "attachment";
}
```